# How to grab the ajax call (the url) sent from a form using ng-submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have a form which submits data to my rails backend. When submitted, the form will run an ajax call. The url it use is like this : `http://localhost:3000/panel/vehicles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcode_cont%5D=66`. How can I grab this url the form sends using `ng-submit`?

Comment: Angularjs and javascript is on client side and you are taking about the listening the request which is basically a function of server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" ng-value="getUrl()"/>

$scope.getUrl = function(){
  return $location.absUrl();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It gets the url without the params. I need the params.

Comment: I changed it to `absUrl`

Comment: Thanks but still the same. abs gets the current URL in the browser